# Compilation error "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 register int i = 0;
 for(i=0;i < 10; i++){
   printf("\n i : %d  \n",i);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I was trying a sample program of registers use in the loop counter.

I'm getting the following error while trying to compile the program,

```
register.c:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
```

How to fix this compilation error.

Comment: Your post included a `#` before the `include` but the error only shows up w/o the `#`.

Comment: [Compiles fine for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7d9e057df40c12489af1bb1de31083ce-03c7ad7a95874ec14b9169a49c662b64).

Comment: also the error is in the first line, so you don't need to post the rest...

Comment: this question adds nothing to the future visitors.... either @Angus should delete it or some body close it :)

Comment: **LEARN TO READ THE ERROR.**  The error says its on Line 1.  If you read Line #1, character by character, you should find the error almost immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Try `#include <stdio.h>`
You need the #.

Comment: Yeah .. i missed in a hurry.Typo error. Thanks .

Comment: Nops, a space between `include` and `<stdio.h>` is not required

Comment: It was either the lack of # (as in the original post) or maybe his compiler for some reason doesn't like the lack of space.  It appears though that the issue has been resolved.  I've never seen someone not using a space after `#include` so I guess I assumed it was enforced...

Comment: Edited to reflect comments.  Thanks!  I learned something :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine but you could put a space at

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Hope that works or theres something wrong with compiler: maybe